# Apigee cannot update / delete user - HectorException

Tags: android, apigee, apigee-baas

I am unable to delete or update certain properties of an entity. It seems as if the index of this entity has been corrupted. I have seen these problems before on Stack Overflow, but this error is not like anything I have seen before:

```
{
 "error": "hector",
 "timestamp": 1422868360331,
 "duration": 1,
 "exception": "me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HectorException",
 "error_description": "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0"
}
```

These issues only seem to occur only on testing accounts tied to the Android SDK, I have no idea if this is a coincidence or this is linked, but perhaps someone else has had similar problem and knows a solution?

Comment: Are you able to delete the user or make the update in the admin portal?  Or via cURL?

Comment: Unfortunately not in the admin portal or in the shell (via admin portal). GET is fine, PUT works on some properties but not others (such as a custom named property named = 'gallery': <array>), DELETE doesn't work at all.

Comment: That hector exception is a very generic error and doesn't give much to go on.  Can you share the call you are trying to make?

Comment: Of course, this is the request we are trying to make with the Android SDK: `facebookInfoEntity.put("gallery", gallery);  client.updateEntityAsync(UUID, facebookInfoEntity, new ApiResponseCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(ApiResponse apiResponse) {
            }` - This being a simple PUT request to a property named "gallery". This doesn't work admin (portal) side either. It's like this property has become corrupted

Comment: So you are trying to do something like this:  PUT /mycollection/myentity {"gallery":"some value"}.  Correct?  Does this only happen on this particular entity?  Or is it happening on all entities?  What does your payload look like?  If you want, you can send this to me directly:  rod at apigee.com

Comment: That's correct, there are several other entities being updated however this is the only one that's causing an issue, the error returned on the android side is a file not found exception. 

The gallery entity payload is just a normal string array list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to a bug in BaaS which we have resolved.  It had to do with the transpoirt-layer size of a batch mutation flush.

Are you still having this problem?